# Not able to send the Enter command on pyserial

Tags: python, cmd, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to send command to a serial com to a gps hardware from the windows with below python script using pyserial. 
The script runs fine and do what is expected from the command.Except I have to press "Enter" , only then the command performs the expected result.
I have tried many ways to send enter but not able to perform the command. How can I prevent pressing enter with the command below to achieve the task. Please assit. This seems very easy but I am not able to get past through it from past 1 week.

```
import serial

port = "COM103"
baud = 115200

ser = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=1)
if ser.isOpen():
     print(ser.name + ' is open...')

while True:
    if cmd == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        print('Sending..')
        ser.write("run MODE-55")
        ser.write("\r")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check which command does your device support, it can be `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n`. Since you are using Windows, it seems that the last one is used, because `\r\n` is a sequence for `Enter` in Windows. Or this could be `\n` because `\r` was sent already.

Also, you don't need to use two commands where it can be done by one:

```
    ser.write("run MODE-55\r\n")
```